# angular 8 auto trigger click event not working

Tags: javascript, angular

i want to automate the button click on  `ngOnInit()` in previous angular version it work fine but now it 
shows   `cannot read property 'click' of null`

here is my code 
html

```html
<button type="button" id="auto_trigger" (click)="editModal(editcontent,param_asset_ref)" class="btn btn-warning">click</button>
```

ts file

```js
let element:HTMLElement = document.getElementById('auto_trigger') as HTMLElement;
```

```js
element.click();
```

Comment: try `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOninit`.  as I assume your `click` is executed before the template load. That's why `DOM` is unable to find `element`

Comment: @PHPNinja it won't help  result is same

Comment: try `ngAfterViewInit{   setTimeout(function(){ let element:HTMLElement = document.querySelector('#auto_trigger') as HTMLElement;
element.click(); }, 3000);   }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is working example implemented have a look
 [angular-8-auto-trigger-click-event-not-working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-tka4hm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

add below code in app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    let element:HTMLElement = document.getElementById('auto_trigger') as HTMLElement;
  // add this condition will solve issue  
  if(element){
    element.click();
    }
  }

  editModal(editcontent,param_asset_ref){
    console.log('clicked');
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<button type="button" id="auto_trigger" (click)="editModal(editcontent,param_asset_ref)" class="btn btn-warning">click</button>
```

Comment: what object required? can you explain?

Comment: if in the ngOnInit()  must auto trigger the button